# Get HttpWebResponse headers WITHOUT redirecting

Tags: c#, http, redirect, header, httpwebresponse

I want to check if a particular page gets redirected or not. However, whenever I try this the headers I get back seem to be from the redirected page, not the initially requested page (and, in particular, the status is OK rather than the 302 I want to see).

Is there something I can set so that it won't automatically follow the redirects?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.example.com/page.html");
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("HTTP Code: " + response.StatusCode + "\r\n\r\n" + response.StatusDescription);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the request should follow redirection responses.
>   
> ...
> If AllowAutoRedirect is set to false, all responses with an HTTP status code from 300 to 399 is returned to the application.